# Function output in the form of list

Tags: python

I am trying to print some prime numbers fetched from excel based on some condition.
I want output as :

```
values fetched are 2, 4, 6 from excel
```

But am getting output as

```
values fetched are 2 from excel

values fetched are 4 from excel

values fetched are 6 from excel
```

Code I've tried so far:

```
def prim(): 
    global K
    global excel_value
    co = 0
    for ro in range(sheet.nrows):
        if sheet.cell_value(ro,1)=='Yes':
             K = sheet.cell_value(ro,co)
             excel_value = K.encode('ascii')
             #print(excel_value) # output ---->2 4 6
             #sys.stdout.write(str(excel_value)+','+' ') # output --> 2, 4, 6
             output1 = 'values fetched are'+  excel_value +'from excel) 
             sys.stdout.write(output1)
prim()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get `stdout` out of the loop, like this:

```
def prim(): 
    global K
    global excel_value
    co = 0
    l =[]
    for ro in range(sheet.nrows):
        if sheet.cell_value(ro,1)=='Yes':
             K = sheet.cell_value(ro,co)
             excel_value = K.encode('ascii')
             l.append(excel_value)
    if l:
        output1 = 'values fetched are ' +  ','.join(l) +' from excel' 
    else:
        output1 = 'Nothing' 
    sys.stdout.write(output1)
```

Comment: Getting error like NameError: global name 'output1' is not defined.....seems this output1 should define globally

Comment: @GeethaAnand I updated my answer and add full function body. if the problem still remains define it globally cus I don't know your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list outside of the loops and append `excel_value`to it each time, then take the `stdout` out of the loop and replace the `excel_value`in the `stdout` with the new list. This will no longer print the value each time a new one is found, it will print them all in one go once they have all been discovered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I take stdout from the loop then am getting error like TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: Got it, now its working fine, I have included std out inside the IF statement only and now am getting my output...thank you all for the help

Comment: No problem, sorry for no code example -- I was short on time